# Google Map Api V2, Customized Route marker

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I used Directions.loadFromWaypoints(Waypoint[], DirectionQueryOptions, DirectionsCallback) to get a route from my current location to destination but the function creates two default markers. Does anyone know how to replace the default markers with my own markers?